# NullReferenceException was unhandled, when making SlimDX screen capture in C#

Tags: c#, exception, screenshot, slimdx

Trying to make a screenshot with SlimDX:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using SlimDX.Direct3D9;
using SlimDX;

namespace dxcapture
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Device device;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface surface = device.GetRenderTarget(0))
            {
                using (SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface surface2 = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(device, surface.Description.Width, surface.Description.Height, surface.Description.Format, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Pool.SystemMemory))
                {
                    device.GetRenderTargetData(surface, surface2);
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(surface2, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 110, 110)));
                    bitmap.Save(@"c:\wqwqwqwqwqwqwqwq.bmp");
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Getting an error:

NullReferenceException was unhandled.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at the line:

```
using (SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface surface = device.GetRenderTarget(0))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize 'device'.

You have`public Device device;` in the class definition but its never assigned.

Comment: Although I'm assuming the call to InitializeComponent() in the constructor initializes 'device', that is a good point.

Comment: I've tried to move "Device" Above and Below InitializeComponent() as was suggested in different stackoverflow issue but it did nothing..

Comment: I don't think it will. Device is explicitly defined by the user in this case, so you would expect an initialisation to follow...

Comment: See what assuming gets you? :)  BTW, I checked out the SlimDX documentation; there's no empty constructor exposed. I think this answer is probably it.

Comment: thanks guys! Seems like I've messed up "Device" by not applying any parameters to it ;) Look at the "Edit 1" for more info.

Comment: @Jeremy S, InitializeComponent is a auto-generated method that initializes UI elements referenced in the .designer file. It won't do anything for local variables.